# Combining (and converting) TIFF separations into 1 bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, tiff

is there a simple way to take a number of 1-bit TIFF files (say, 4 for CMYK) and convert it into one contone RGB bitmap?

This problem has me stumped..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply shell out to ImageMagick, is that an acceptable option?

Comment: I suppose that's a valid answer, however i'm looking for the quickndirty solution... :S

Comment: This is a quick and dirty option: I mean install imagemagick on your server, then run "convert c.tif m.tif y.tif k.tif -set colorspace CMYK -combine combined.tif" from the command prompt. You can get C# to run that command for you and deal with the temporary files if you need.

Comment: Here's some people discussing the same problem: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12704